# MongoDB, fetch a name and max age using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB. I'm trying to get a person's name who has max age. Here is a sample of my document:

```
    {
        "_id": ....
        "name": Alex,
        "age": 23,
        "city": NYC,
        "isActive": False
    }
    {
        "_id": .....
        "name": Kate,
        "age": 25,
        "city": SFO,
        "isActive": True
    }
    {
        "_id": .....
        "name": Dane,
        "age": 31,
        "city": SFO,
        "isActive": null
    }
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```
db.person.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {name: "$name", age: "$age"}}}, {$group: {_id: "", age: {$max: "$_id.age"}}}])
```

but I get only the age in the final output.

```
{ "_id" : "", "age" : 31 }
```

Is there a way to add the name is second pipe?

Comment: This actually is not an aggregation at all. All you need do is sort the cursor and retrieve the top document `db.person.find().sort({ "age": -1 }).limit(1)`. Noting that [`$orderBy`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) in argument to `.findOne()` is deprecated now.

Comment: If you really must use aggregation then the same thing is `db.person.aggregate([{ "$sort": { "age": -1 } },{ "$limit": 1 }])`. Throw in a `$project` if you just want specific properties, or simply use projection with a standard `.find()` as is demonstrated.

Comment: I am trying to go with aggregate.  Thanks for your second suggestion, `db.person.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {name: "$name", age: "$age"}}}, {$sort: {"_id.age": -1}}, {$limit: 1}])` worked for me